# Symfony2 - Passing parameter from the Controller to the FormType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony2. I want to pass a parameter from the Controller to the FormType :
this my Action :

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $employee = $this->getUser();
        if (null === $employee) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("L'employé est anonyme.");
        } else {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $abs = new Absence();
            $form = $this->createForm(new AbsenceType($employee), $abs);
            if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
                    $employee->addAbsence($abs);
                    $em->persist($employee);
                    $em->flush();
                    $this->addFlash('notice', 'absence  bien enregistrée.');
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pfe_time_absence_index'));
                }
            }
            return $this->render('PFETimeBundle:Absence:add.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
```

This is my FormType :

```
class AbsenceType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $sup;
    public function __construct (  Employee $profile)
    {
        $this->sup = $profile;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $supp=$this->sup;
        $builder
            ->add('employee', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PFEUserBundle:Employee',
                'property'=>'matricule',
                 'query_builder' => function(EmployeeRepository $er) use ($supp){
                 return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->where("e.parent.matricule = :matricule")
                    ->orderBy('e.nom', 'ASC')
                    ->setParameter('matricule', $supp->getMatricule())
                    ;
                }
            ))
            ->add('dateDebut','date')
            ->add('dateFin','date')
            ->add('motif', 'choice', array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices'  => array('Non'=>'Non','Oui'=>'Oui'),))
            ->add('motif','textarea')
            ->add('valider','submit')
        ;
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PFE\TimeBundle\Entity\Absence'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pfetime_bundle_absence_type';
    }
}
```

the query get all children of the employee and pass them to the entity list( i am using doctrine extension).
When I execute the action it gives me this error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to PFE\TimeBundle\Form\AbsenceType::PFE\TimeBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of PFE\UserBundle\Entity\EmployeeRepository, instance of Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository given, called in C:\wamp\www\Projet\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\ORMQueryBuilderLoader.php on line 56 and defined
```

Comment: What is `$supp=$this->sup;` ? How is this initialized?

Comment: In the creation of the formType ,the constructor is called and the `$this->sup` is initialized.

Comment: My bad, i scrolled wrong... forgot what i wrote

Answer (score 1):

The actual error you're getting is a problem with the typehint in your `query_builder` closure.

```
function(EmployeeRepository $er) {}
```

Your closure is expecting an instance of `PFE\UserBundle\Entity\EmployeeRepository` but is receiving an instance of `Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository`

There are several things that could cause this, but it's likely to be one of these two

1. Your `Employee` entity doesn't define the `repositoryClass` as defined [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories)
2. Your `EmployeeRepository` class doesn't inherit from `Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository`

All that being said, you should look into [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html) for features like this.